# Dynamically update <a href link..> when <SELECTED> value is changed

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

[image]I am working on my school application using jsp and web-development is new to me.
At this moment I am stumbled upon the issue:

The process should be this:

I have a Dropdown box with multiple values.
For example:

Room: 111 | Building: ACC | Capacity: 15

Room: 111 | Building: ACD | Capacity: 25

Room: 151 | Building: ACC | Capacity: 11

Room: 113 | Building: ACC | Capacity: 15

When user selects ANY option nothing should happen.

Next to the dropdown box, I have a `<a href link..>` which sais "see the chart".

When user presses "see the chart" the following process should take place:

1. String in selected box should be separated and Room# and Bulding# must be extracted into separate strings
2. new windowshould open with this link:
   room_chart.jsp?room=111&building=ACC (for example)

I know how to split the string and do it in general, but I don't know how to dynamically do it without reloading the page... I guess I would need to implement the JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call a Javascript function in the anchor's href attribute. In that function use `document.getElementById` with the select box's `id` to get the [selected string](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_select.asp), split it, and send an [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) request or open a new window with [window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) (but that's not dynamic).

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function view_chart() {
            var select = document.getElementById("room_select");
            var option = select.options.item(select.selectedIndex).value;
            var tokens = option.split(/[:|]/);
            var url = "room_chart.jsp?room="+trim(tokens[1])+"&building="+trim(tokens[3]);
            window.open(url);
        }

        function trim(value) {
            value = value.replace(/^\s+/,'');
            value = value.replace(/\s+$/,'');
            return value;
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <select id="room_select">
          <option>Room: 014 | Building: ACT</option>
          <option>Room: 005 | Building: ACC</option>
        </select>
        <a href="javascript:view_chart()">Show Info</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wasn't the one to vote you down, but I can say that's pretty bad accessibility. Can't see where the link goes, can't open in a new tab, etc.

Comment: Guess a case of "Not enough jQuery" ツ   Disclaimer: I didn't downvote your answer http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question/48195#48195

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery , if thats possible, to replace the href element with a brand new element with updated url , based on selection from the dorp down.